# How can I periodically execute some function if this function takes along time to run (less than peroid)

Tags: c++

I want to run a function for example func() exactly 1 time per second. However the running time of func() is about 500 ms. How Can I do that? I know if the running time of the function is low, I can write a while loop in func() and sleep() for 1 second after each execution. But now, the running time is high. What should I do to ensure the func() run exactly 1 time per second? Thanks.

Comment: Windows or linux? do you want your code to be portable? You can use timers, but on windows i'd recommend [`CreateTimerQueueTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yo do:

1. Take the current time in start_time.
2. Perform your job
3. Take the current time in end_time
4. Wait for (1 second + start_time - end_time)

That way, you can perform your tasks every seconds reliably. If the task takes less time, you will wait longer and vice versa. Note however that this assumes that your task takes always less than 1 sec. to execute. In the real code, you want to check for that before the sleep statement.

Implementation details depend on the platform.

Note that using this method still results in a small drift due to the time it takes to compute step 4. A more accurate alternative would be to synchronize on integer multiple of one second. That way, over 1000s of cycles you would not drift.

It depends on the level of accuracy you need.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me more detail about the integer synchronize? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a brute, easy to code solution, you can get the time before first run of the function and save it in some variable (start_time). Create repeat index count variable (repeat_number) that stores next repeat number. Then you can do kinda this:

```
1) next_run_time = ++repeat_number*1sec + start_time;
2) func();
3) wait_time = next_run_time - current_time;
4) sleep(wait_time)
5) goto 1;
```

This approach disables accumulation of time error on each iteration.

But for the real application you should find some event framework or library.

Comment: Thanks. When should I get the current_time?

Comment: current_time is current time at the moment when you calculate wait_time. =)

Comment: I think I got it. So the next_run_time is accurate time right?

Comment: Yes. next_run_time is always an "ideal" scheduled time to run the func(). So on each iteration you will be synchronized with scheduled time. And each iteration error will be only the system errors with sleep() and the time you make some code to calculate current time. And this error will not accumulate on each iteration, because next_run_time doesn't depend on anything random on each iteration.